# How do I load jsoup Java library from inside Coldfusion 2016?

Tags: java, coldfusion, jsoup, coldfusion-2016

TLDR: CreateObject function throws an exception (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) because it cannot see the java class/JAR file.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks

---

**contents of Application.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent output="true">

    <cfset path = "#Mid(CGI.CF_TEMPLATE_PATH, 1, FindNoCase("index.cfm", CGI.CF_TEMPLATE_PATH)-2)#/java/lib" />
    <cfoutput>path: #path#</cfoutput>

    <cftry>
        <cfset This.javaSettings = {LoadPaths = ["#path#/", "#path#/java/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar", "./java/lib/", "./java/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar"], loadColdFusionClassPath = true, reloadOnChange = true}>

        <cfset jsoup = CreateObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup") />

        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" />
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

    <cfabort>
</cfcomponent>
```

**JAR file location**

```
/Volumes/mydrive/work/myapp/java/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar
```

**output of the cfoutput inside Application.cfc**

```
path: /Volumes/mydrive/work/myapp/java/lib
```

Comment: The `#path#` logic will fail when the requested template is *not* index.cfm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mrjayviper, I'm not sure why you have added  the **jsoup-1.12.1.jar** in more times in loadPaths array ?

As well as your `PATH = > /Volumes/mydrive/work/myapp/java/lib`, But you have passed the value in loadPaths array like `#path#/java/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar.` Then it's should consider it as `/Volumes/mydrive/work/myapp/java/lib/java/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar` So it's totally wrong. That's an causes of your problem.

Here I wish to give some better solution for you with my sample application,

My simple application files structure look like this,

- Application.cfc : Just normal Application.cfc file which having
  this.javaSettings to load the JSOUP jar file
- index.cfm : Having code to fetching web page content using jSoup & executes the parsing operation
- jsoup-1.8.3.jar : The downloaded JSOUP jar file

[image]

Then you can set the javaSetting in **application.cfc** file like below

```
component {
    this.name = "jSoupParser";
    //Loads the JAR File
    this.javaSettings = { loadPaths = [ "#expandPath('./jsoup-1.8.3.jar')#" ], 
                            reloadOnChange = false };
}
```

You could use the expandPath() and can point out your current application directory. 
Then you can create an object in your cfm file like below 
**Index.cfm** :

```
<cfset getJsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup")>
```

I hope this help you more. If you want more explanation / clarification about this then please visit below link. Already my team gave the sample for this jSoup. https://www.mitrahsoft.com/index.cfm/blog/ColdFusion-Web-scraping-HTML-Parsing-using-JSOUP.

Answer (score 1):

Though technically there's nothing wrong with using absolute paths - you don't need them in this case. It's simpler to use a relative path, pointing to a subdirectory. For example: `./java/lib` *Also, don't include the same path multiple times*.

```
<cfcomponent>
    <!--- don't forget to name the application ---> 
    <cfset This.name = "SomeUniqueApplicationName">
    <cfset This.javaSettings = { LoadPaths = ["./java/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar"] }>
</cfcomponent>
```

Then CF will be able to find the class when needed.

```
<cfset jsoup = CreateObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup") />
```

Comment: Note, if you want to load ALL jars in that subdirectory,  use `./java/lib/` (no jar name at the end)