# JSOUP URL connect errors in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I have tried to work with JSOUP, Below I've mentioned my code

`Application.cfc` as

```
<cfset this.name = "jsoupApp11111">
<cfset this.javasettings = { loadpaths = [#expandPath("./jsoup-1.12.1.jar")#],reloadOnchange = true}>
```

CFM file as

```
<cfset jsoupObj = createObject("java","org.jsoup.Jsoup")>
<cfset testURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)'>
<cfset connectUrlSite = jsoupObj.connect(testURL).get() >
<cfset getUrlSiteBody = connectUrlSite.body() >
 <cfoutput>
    #connectUrlSite.title()#"
 </cfoutput>

<cfloop array="#getUrlSiteBody.select('img')#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>
        #i#
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

It's working fine for above Wikipedia site URL, When I am trying to do the same for some other websites I get an error message like `Received fatal alert: handshake_failur`
and some other sites throws error message like `PKIX path validation failed` error during jsoupObj.connect(testURL) process. I'm not sure which I'm missed or which place I will get more detail about this kind of errors.

Error message After using http instead of https 
[image]

Every answer is appreciable and helpful.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Every site having different selectors. For example , you r new site ( getUrlSiteBody  ) don't have img means it's not return anything. Could you please post your issue here.

Comment: @kannan.p I am get error message like `Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`  and `PKIX path validation failed`  I get error message from jsoupObj.connect(URl) place. Not error message from  `getUrlSiteBody.select('img')`

Comment: *which place I will get more detail about this kind of errors* Do a search on the 2 error messages you posted. They're jre errors indicating a problem establishing a secure connection to a particular site.

Comment: @Ageax I did google search but bad luck I can't able to get the exact reason and exact solutions so that I've posted that as a question.

Comment: There are different causes. Depends on the complete error message, your jre version and the site you're trying to load. Start with the error from one specific site work from there.  For us to assist, we'd need to see the failing url, your exact java version and the full error stack trace.

Comment: You appear to be using ColdFusion.  Any reason you're not using CFHTTP to fetch the webpage?  That's the method I always use in order to handle potential redirects, resolving URL paths and not aborting when an error occurs (throwonerror).

Comment: @JamesMoberg - My guess is he wants to take advantage of JSoup's parsing. These appear to be a jre issues (non-trusted certs, tlsv1.2, etc..), in which case they'd need to be fixed for cfhttp as well.

Comment: @Ageax ahh... I mostly use CFX_HTTP5 to get around most java-based web request issues (& ignore cert errors). I didn't realize that CF2016 was also having issues with the URL.

Comment: Saravana, Could you please visit below two link. I hope that will help you more.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138765/coldfusion-java-method-not-found-exception/51140516#51140516

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968263/how-do-i-load-jsoup-java-library-from-inside-coldfusion-2016/57969946#57969946

Comment: And try to use HTTP instead of HTTPS in your url.

Comment: @Ageax I have tried JSOUP JAR latest version  `jsoup-1.12.1.jar`  https://trycf.com/ is one of my testing URL I got error message `Received fatal alert: handshake_failur`. After applying kannan suggestions I got Http URL Fetching error.

Comment: @Kannan.P When I am using HTTP instead of HTTPS It's working fine for `PKIX path validation failed` error thrown site. I'm sure both sites which is used in my testing are https enabled sites.So I'm not sure why this happening and exact reason for this issue.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar - Yes, like I said the errors when using http**S** are because it can't establish the secure connection.  You forgot to mention your java version. If you're using something like 1.8.0_72, try updating to 1.8.0_144+. That worked for me.  *I got Http URL Fetching error* Many sites don't allow automated screen scraping and reject requests with an empty  user-agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out some pertinent information (like your java version), but generally speaking those https errors are caused by JSoup being unable to establish a secure connection with the target server.

**Received fatal alert: handshake_failure**

I was able to reproduce the error with java 1.8.0_72. Enabling debugging, i.e. `-Djavax.net.debug=all`, confirmed it's caused by an [SNI server_name extension bug](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u141-bugfixes-3720387.html). Updating the [JVM used by CF](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2014/09/how-to-change-upgrade-jdk-version-of-coldfusion-server/) to version 1.8.0_141 or later, resolved the issue.

- *Java 1.8.0_144 (fixed)*

  ```
  *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
  ...
  Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: ...
  Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=trycf.com]
  ***
  ```
- *Java 1.8.0_72 (server_name missing)*

  ```
  *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
  ...
  Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: ...
  ***
  ```

**HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403**

HTTP Status code 403 means the request is forbidden. In this case the request is being rejected because the [user-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) value is empty. See the documentation on [adding a user agent](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#userAgent-java.lang.String-).

Just keep in mind some sites deliberately reject such requests to prevent screen scraping. So check the site's terms and conditions first, to see if programmatic access is prohibited.

**PKIX path validation failed**

You need to supply the URL causing the error for us to be more specific, but generally it indicates a problem with missing or invalid certificates. See also [How to Resolve Java HTTPS Exceptions](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/852.cfm)

Comment: Previously I had a Java version `1.8.0_144` but It's thrown an error, Now I have updated my java version into `1.8.0_221`.Now It's working fine for both errors thrown sites. Thanks..!

Comment: Interesting. Which site was throwing a PKIX validation error? Wondering if it's related to the removal of some certs in [1.8.0_221](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u221-relnotes-5480116.html). Anyway, glad it's all working now!